# How to set a field in the parent class in R using reference classes?

Tags: r, reference-class

I'm trying to set the `params` field and validate it in the Template class, so I can do `TemplateClass$new(params)` and it automatically validates, but I get an error:

```
Template <- setRefClass('Template',
    fields = c(
       "params"
    ),

    methods = list(
        initialize = function(params){
            params <<- params
            validate_params()
        },
        validate_params = function(){
            "everything okay"
        }
    )
)

PointsTemplate <- setRefClass('PointsTemplate',

    contains = "Template",

    methods = list(
        initialize = function(params){
            callSuper(params)
        }
    )
)

Error in .Object$initialize(...) :
  argument "params" is missing, with no default
```

**EDIT**: I seemed to have solved it by changing the `initialize` method in the `Template` class to `initialize = function(params = NULL){}`. But I don't understand why this is needed.

Also, I've seen other people use `callSuper()` when the class doesn't contain any super classes. What is the reason for this?

Comment: FYI every class has a super class. If it's not explicitly specified it's the base "envRefClass".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any experience with  R reference classes but using the help of `?ReferenceClasses`  you can read the following:

> Initialization methods need some care in design, as
>   they do for S4 classes. Therefore, your method should normally include ... as an
>   argument, all other arguments should have defaults or check for
>   missingness, and your method should pass all initialized values on via
>   $callSuper() or $initFields() if you know that your superclasses have
>   no initialization methods.

So I understand this by setting my initialization function in the parent class using ... and named parameters for all fields with a default values.

```
Template <- setRefClass('Template',
                        fields = list(params="list"),
                        methods = list(initialize = 
                            function(...,params=list(1:5)){
                              callSuper(...,params=params)
                              validate_params()
                            },
                          validate_params = function(){
                            "everything okay"
                          }
                        )
)
```

For the sub-Class no need to initialize parameters  since I am sure that super class will dot it.

```
PointsTemplate <- setRefClass('PointsTemplate',
                              contains = "Template",
                              methods = list(initialize = 
                                 function(...){
                                  callSuper(...)
                                }

                             ))
```

No testing the initialization:

```
## using default values
> PointsTemplate$new()
Reference class object of class "PointsTemplate"
Field "params":
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
## setting params 
 PointsTemplate$new(params=list(1:10))
Reference class object of class "PointsTemplate"
Field "params":
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: nice example. Why there is no message `"everything okay"` as per `validate_params` function?

Comment: @DanielKrizian maybe I should add ` message("everything okay")`